# Mapeamento com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework, mvc

Boa tarde,

ao analisar um código vejo no mapeamento a seguinte linha:

```
this.HasKey(t => t.IdEstudante);
```

Entendo o que faz na prática porém não teoricamente, se refere ao objeto porém explicitamente o que esse parâmetro está dizendo? Percorre os objetos e ve quais possuem o parâmetro IdEstudante e dizem que a chave primária é essa?

Abraços.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `HasKey` possui uma assinatura que tem como parâmetro um delegate que recebe a sua entidade como parâmetro e retorna um `object`. Isso significa que o conteúdo que você retornar (em tese pode ser qualquer coisa pois é um `object`) vai ser sua chave primária.

Um exemplo **(apenas exemplo, não utilize essa implementação)** do que você poderia fazer para ver que é aceito é criar um método que atende a assinatura e realizar o teste:

```
public object Teste(Entidade a)
{
    return 10;
}

builder.HasKey(a => Teste(a));
```

Então o método tem a finalidade de definir qual será a chave primária da sua entidade, por esse motivo não definimos um "critério de busca" como você comentou acima, pois ele só precisa de um retorno que o *Entity Framework* utilizará como a chave primária para essa entidade.